# Dealing with null-to-string errors

Tags: java, string, null

I have an object I'm retrieving and turning to a string. The .get() may return null, which in turn crashes when trying to convert to string. What the best way to deal with null in this case? Perhaps set it to an empty string if it returns null. I'm trying to avoid writing an if statement for each .get()

```
 String value1 = userDict.get("key1").toString();
 String value2 = userDict.get("key2").toString();
 String value3 = userDict.get("key3").toString();
 String value4 = userDict.get("key4").toString();
```

EDIT:

userDict is HashMap (String, Object)

Comment: And what do you want returned if the `.get()` method returns null?

Comment: `public String getDictEntry(String key) {
    Object value = userDict.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return value.toString();
    }`

Comment: What type is `userDict`? If you can fit it into a `Properties`, then you can call the appropriate `get()` method with a default value.

Comment: You can write an static utility method with this line - `return obj == null ? "" : obj.toString();`.

Comment: userDict is HashMap (String, Object)

Comment: Thanks Eric. I went with yours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `String.valueOf(userDict.get("key1"))`.  According to [the specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) of `valueOf(Object o)`, it will either call `toString()` on the object or return the string `"null"` if given a null Object.

EDIT: edited to point to the java 7 api instead of the java 6 api.

EDIT 2: If you don't mind making your code a bit more dense, you could encapsulate the logic of this method by using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a):

```
String value1 = (userDict.get("key1") == null) ? "" : userDict.get("key1").toString();
```

Comment: I've never, ever seen a use-case where it was desirable to have "null" stored or printed somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but without a proper use case this seems like a good starting point.  A custom version of this method could easily be written that does something more helpful if given `null`.

Comment: Yea, printing null ain't gonna fly

Comment: Then it looks like you're going to have to write a helper method that takes an Object and returns `""` if the Object is `null` or `o.toString()` if it isn't.  That's very similar to what `String.valueOf(Object o)` is doing (except you'd be returning `""` instead of `"null"`, of course).

Comment: @ono if you can't have `"null"` what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 3):

> Perhaps set it to an empty string if it returns null.

That's up to you.  It depends what the purpose of this code is.

> I'm trying to avoid writing an if statement for each .get()

If you want to avoid repetitive code, then write yourself a helper method.

Comment: @ono: By "helper", I really just mean a little two-line method that factors out the common logic that you would otherwise have to copy-and-paste N times.

Answer (score 0):

As Oli suggested you can create a helper get method like following

```
String helperGet(String key){
    YourClassType t = userDict.get("key1");
    if(t!=null)
       return t.toString();
    else
       return "";
}
```

Now call like following

```
 String value1 = userDict.helperGet("key1");
 String value2 = userDict.helperGet("key2");
 String value3 = userDict.helperGet("key3");
 String value4 = userDict.helperGet("key4");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a helper method. Something like this should work..

```java
protected String getStringFromMap(Map<String,Object> map, String key)
{
   Object value = map.get(key);
   return value != null ? value.toString() : "";
}
```

Then you can call this as follows:

```
String value1 = getStringFromMap(userDict, "key1");
String value2 = getStringFromMap(userDict, "key2");
String value3 = getStringFromMap(userDict, "key3");
String value4 = getStringFromMap(userDict, "key4");
```

Answer (score -4):

I would use a try-catch

```
  try {
    value1 = userDict.get("key1").toString();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    value1 = 0;
  }
```

Comment: That is a very bad idea. For one, testing for null is easier. Furthermore, you catch all unchecked exceptions this way.

Comment: If there are multiple variables: value1, value2, value3, how will you know which variable to set to "" inside catch?